# using super in function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to dynamically create constructors. Thats why I have a factory function which gives back a constructor function. However, when I try to call `super()` in this function, the parser complains that its unexpected there.

```
function makeConstructor (someInput) {
  return function () {
    super() // SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
    // and other stuff depending on someInput
  }
}

class MyClass {
  constructor: makeConstructor(foobar)
}
```

As you can see, when this code would execute, the super call would make totally sense because it is a constructor.

So the question is: How can I ship around this issues? Are there other possibilities to create constructorfunctions like this?

Comment: Ignoring `super`, you can’t define a constructor like that (`constructor: someValue`). (Or even properties like that.) `makeConstructor` can return a class with just a constructor, and then you can add to that class’s prototype (including by just taking the property descriptors from another temporary class’s prototype).

Comment: This seems like a bit of a X-Y question. It might be better to ask about the problem you're actually trying to address by creating these dynamic constructors.

Comment: *"I want to dynamically create constructors."* Since this isn't possible in that way, why not create dynamic classes instead? A class is basically just a constructor. If you need to share methods you can always `extend`.

Comment: This is an X-Y question where you describe a problem with your attempted solution, but don't describe the actual problem.  What is the actual design problem you're really trying to solve?  We can help you much better if we know the higher level design problem.  There are lots of ways to dynamically create objects.  What makes the most sense in your case depends upon what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @loganfsmyth its exactly the problem I have. I dont want dynamic class creation because I would loose all the benefits of using the class syntax.

Comment: @Fuzzyma like what?

Comment: @Fuzzyma I'm sorry, but as is your question is very unclear. It would help a lot of we could have full examples of what you want. For instance, normally I'd expect `makeConstructor` to just do `return class MyClass extends someInput { /* ... */ }` or something if you wanted to create a class dynamically. With no clear goal, it is impossible to say if that would actually address your issue.